# stuck on aws amplify API.graphql(...) call to run query, query works in graphql playground

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, graphql, aws-amplify

Update: I have added at the very bottom the schema and generate query that was working before, it seems the addition of _version seems to breaking something, and I am not sure why.

I can't quite figure this one out. I am getting the following error
`"Cannot return null for non-nullable field Recipe._version."`

It was working prior, but I used aws amplifies new visual data modeling tool and added in the ingredients model. Ran amplify pull and it seemed to break my code, but not exactly sure why.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Note: I am able to run queries and mutations just fine in graphql playground

I have the following code

```
//...
import { listRecipes as ListRecipes } from "./graphql/queries";


async function getData() {
    try {
      const recipeData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(ListRecipes));
      console.log("listData:", recipeData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error fetching recipes...", err);
    }
  }
```

graphql schema

```
type Ingredient
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: private }])
  @key(name: "byRecipe", fields: ["recipeID"]) {
  id: ID!
  amount: String
  ingredient: String
  recipeID: ID!
}

type Recipe @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: private }]) {
  id: ID!
  userId: ID
  name: String!
  description: String!
  recipe: String!
  comments: [Comment] @connection(name: "RecipeComments")
  original_author: String
  Ingredients: [Ingredient] @connection(keyName: "byRecipe", fields: ["id"])
}

type Comment @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: private }]) {
  id: ID!
  message: String
  createdBy: String
  recipe: Recipe @connection(name: "RecipeComments")
}

type Test {
  id: String!
  name: String!
  price_usd: String!
}

type Query {
  getTest(limit: Int, start: Int): [Test] @function(name: "test-${env}")
}
```

Here is the queries.js file that's generated by amplify mock

```
export const listRecipes = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListRecipes(
    $filter: ModelRecipeFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listRecipes(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        userId
        name
        description
        recipe
        original_author
        _version
        _deleted
        _lastChangedAt
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
      startedAt
    }
  }
`;
```

So before I added in the Ingredients model with the data model ui editor I had the following schmea and querie.js file that was working.

schema

```
type Recipe @model {
  id: ID!
  userId: ID
  name: String!
  description: String!
  recipe: String!
  comments: [Comment] @connection(name: "RecipeComments")
}

type Comment
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, queries: null, ownerField: "createdBy" }]) {
  id: ID!
  message: String
  createdBy: String
  recipe: Recipe @connection(name: "RecipeComments")
}

type Test {
  id: String!
  name: String!
  price_usd: String!
}

type Query {
  getTest(limit: Int, start: Int): [Test] @function(name: "test-${env}")
}
```

queries.js

```
export const listRecipes = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListRecipes(
    $filter: ModelRecipeFilterInput
    $limit: Int
    $nextToken: String
  ) {
    listRecipes(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
      items {
        id
        userId
        name
        description
        recipe
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      nextToken
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: Has `DataStore` been part of this project? IIRC that's one of the "private" fields it uses to sync. I think while you can _read_ using GraphQL for a DataStore-managed storage layer, if you absolutely have to, you shouldn't _write_ data with regular GraphQL if you're using DataStore. I don't know how many of these objects you have, but you can manually stub in a random value for `_version` now and you should be able to list objects with the usual DataStore APIs (`DataStore.query(Recipe)`).

Comment: I hadn't been using DataStore in the project. I had followed this code to build what I have. https://github.com/dabit3/aws-appsync-react-workshop/tree/master Are you recommending to move to DataStore anyways? As far a adding in a random value for `_version` is that only for DataStore, I tried creating a mutation where I added a value to `_version` and my mutation does not work. The strange thing is in graphql playground everything works, but in my front end it doesn't see the recipe object.

Comment: After reading the datastore docs, it seems like it is intended for supporting offline data creation, right now I don't need that, so I don't see how it would be the correct solution for the issue I am having.

Comment: just remove this (`_version`) field from queries.js ? ... probably some existing DB entry doesn't have this field defined ... just don't ask/query for this

Comment: ok but the queries are automatically generated when I write amplify mock?

Comment: I don't think you should edit the auto-generated queries. It looks like `_version` [comes from AppSync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/conflict-detection-and-sync.html). It should be automatically managed; any chance you created an instance of an object without using AppSync?